# Is it OK to use while loops as a timing mechanism?

Tags: wait, thread-sleep

In general is it ever good practice to use a while loop as a timing/waiting mechanism. If you need high accuracy and it is only a few milliseconds that will need to be blocked for.

I am currently writing a game-loop in Java/Scala but this question is not targeting a specific circumstance. I understand it **always** depends on the circumstance whether it is a good idea but I am asking if it could reasonably be a good idea in a reasonable amount of situations.

EDIT:

If you think it is a bad idea please offer an alternative that will maintain a high amount of accuracy. Simply using a system timer can give a huge variation (at least in Java it does) which is a deal breaker.

Comment: I would say no... the delays through calculations were used because there wasn't anything else, nowadays it is very bad because you would need to create a version for each cpu speed. And if other programs are taking cycles it will not be fluent.

Comment: A few milliseconds is a huge amount of time for a processor. You should sleep the thread if you want that large a delay. Spinning is OK and often preferrable for smaller time intervals where you might not want to give up the CPU.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a loop to delay your execution is one of the worst ways to delay a thread because it consumes CPU. Instead of doing that, you can use:

```
Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
```

It does not consume CPU at all. However, you should remember that functions working with threads are not absolutely accurate, so the time given in the argument of sleep function may take a little more time than you have entered, but it is so little that can be easily ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Execution time is not constant and depends on many factors like CPU speed,OS(time sharing of CPU yields different result) etc. Moreover a machine which can perform 10e9 cycles per second, milliseconds are huge among time.Hence using loops for timer is very bad idea,try to use your language's or Os' timer instead.